# Check if a cursor has timed out or not

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Is it possible to check if an open cursor has timed out yet on the database or not? The `.alive` property does not appear to update without actually calling `next()`, but that would also cause the cursor position to advance, which I don't want.

Background: I'm lazy-loading data to a web client, and I'm keeping the cursor open server-side so the client can request more data from it. I'm letting the cursors time out by Mongo, since that's good enough for the use case and simplifies guaranteed garbage collection of cursors. However, that leaves me to manage the open cursor references Python-side, which I'm doing with an occasional garbage collection cycle. During this cycle, I'd like to throw away any cursors which have already timed out on Mongo's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [changelog.rst](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver) for the PyMongo driver, the `alive` method is deprecated on `MongoClient` since it no longer provides meaningful information. Even if the Mongo Client is disconnected, it may discover a server in time to fulfill the next operation. `alive` is still available at cursor level, however, it only provides meaningful information for a tailable cursor as they may temporarily stop iteration. For normal cursors the only reliable method to verify if a cursor is still alive is by calling `next()`.

If calling `next()` is a problem, you can rewind the cursor and replay it to the last record using a snippet similar to the one below:

```
recordCount = 10
cursor.rewind()
counter = 0
for _ in cursor:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == recordCount:
        break
```

Comment: Hmm, how disappointing. :) Also no server API that would allow me to query the status of a cursor?

Comment: No. The only reliable way to verify if a cursor is still alive is by running a query against the database. You could use rewind()  to get the cursor back to its original position if calling next() creates a problem.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that I can call `next`, then rewind, then `skip` to the position I was at before? Then this could indeed solve the problem.

Comment: Turns out in my case I also need to do the same with `CommandCursor`s, which don't support rewinding, so this is not really an option after all. I'll have to go with simply keeping track of the last-used time myself and cleaning them up this way. Thanks for confirming the available options though!